# C# multiline comment regex not working

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to regex and i'm trying to make a regex that find all C-style block comments (/* and */)

So I search the web and find a good one who works on RegExr.com!

```
/\/\*[^]*?\*\//g
```

But when I want to put this regex in my C# code, it throws me an error.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex _reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"/\/\*[^]*?\*\//g");
```

Can you help me finding my error ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the regex delimiters, and use singleline mode with `.` (either inline `(?s)` or `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag) to match any character including a newline:

```
(?s)/\*.*?\*/
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fs)%2F%5C*.*%3F%5C*%2F&i=Text%0D%0A%2F*%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20Multiline%20Comments%0D%0A*%2F%0D%0A%2F*%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20Multiline%20Comments%0D%0A*%2F%0D%0Atext)

In your regex, you have `[^]` that matches any symbol including a newline that is only working in JavaScript. And `/.../[modifier]` is not necessary in C# since flags can be specified as optional parameters in regex class methods.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Regex are a total mystery for me right now but i'll get better! One more time thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome. Just in case, here is a C# snippet: `var rx = new Regex(@"/\*.*?\*/", RegexOptions.Singleline);`.